# How to set the output size in `savefig()` in `GR.jl`

Tags: plot, julia, gr

I have a simple question about using `GR.jl` directly (Not using `Plots.jl`).
I am displaying an image of size `300x300`.

I want to display it on screen and save the plot with `savefig`:

```
using GR

img = rand(300, 300)

imshow(img)

savefig("img.png")
```

I expect the output to have size of `300x300` yet I get much bigger size.

How can I control the output size?

I saw https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/2303 yet I am not sure if it is related.

Answer (score 1):

`savefig("img.png", height = 300, width = 300)` should produce the correct size PNG. For further modifications you can use the functions in the `Images` package on your `img` prior to writing to file.